# Redirect IP:3000 to domain name

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy

I have a node.js app running at `MY_SERVER_IP:3000`.

I want that my app should run on `somedomain.com/myapp`.

I've been read that need to edit something called `apache.conf`.

Can someone explain me if this apache.conf is global for my server and how can I redirect my app to  `https://somedomain.com/myapp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Point your dns A records to that ip.
2. Create a new vhost in apache (google how)
3. Change server port to 80 if you dont want people to specify it in the url. Otherwise no further changes are required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by changing the server pot to 80 you mean changing 3000 to 80?

Comment: Thats correct. You would find that in server config file, its easy to spot and change